# Get additional function from baseclass

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm relatively new to C++. We have an abstract base class and 2 derived class.

```
class PositionBase  (abstract)
class PositionLenght: PositionBase
class PositionAngle:  PositionBase
```

the PositionBase contains functionality like getting the name.
The derived classes have methods like `GetLenght()` or `GetAngle();`

The (old) application contains an array which contains the derived classes.

Suppose, I get the object from `array[1]` and based on its type, I want to run  `GetLength() or GetAngle()`. Then I need to know the object type I get from the array.

When I use:

```
 if(PositionBase->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(PositionLenght))))
        {do something}
```

it does not work. What works is

```
if(typeid(*PositionBase) == typeid(PositionLenght)))
    {do something}
```

I can also just "`dynamic_cast`" the object and if it doesn't return NULL, I'm good.

In `C#` I would use interfaces, what is the preferred way to deal with this in `C++`?

Comment: In C++ a purely abstract class could be considered to be an "interface".

Comment: Also please don't describe your code, try to create a [mcve] to show it instead.

Comment: This kind of conditional logic based on class type is a code smell.  The traditional OOP way to handle this would be to move that logic into the derived classes, call it through the base interface, and let polymorphism handle choosing which version of the function is called.

Comment: If you need to know a class is of given type, then **don't store it as another type**. If you have an array of `PositionLenght` and another array of `PositionAngle`, the problem solves itself.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, what you need is:

In C++ you can store pointers to derived class into an array of pointers to base(abstract) class. 
From there, 
when you fetch your pointer to base from array, 
If you need specific function from derived class,
than you need to
use dynamic_cast to cast to derived from base and check result to see if cast succeeded and if you can call function you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same (as in C#). You define virtual function in base class and override it with required functionality in derived classes:

```
class PositionBase {
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};
class PositionLenght: public PositionBase {
    void do_something() override {
        std::cout << "doing something for length\n";
    }
};
class PositionAngle: public PositionBase {
    void do_something() override {
        std::cout << "doing something for angle\n";
    }
};
int main() {
    PositionBase *arr[] = {
        new PositionLenght(),
        new PositionAngle(),
    };
    for(auto i = 0; i < 2; ++i) arr[i]->do_something();
}
```

will print:

```
doing something for length
doing something for angle
```

Comment: Radoslaw, I understand what you mean but in my case, the PositionAngle has a methode GetAngle() and the PositionLength has a methode GetLength(). Those methods aren't defined in the base class

Comment: You asked for "preffered" way. :) If you can modify base class, then add abstract method to base and override it in derived classes, calling `GetAngle` and `GetLength` in respective classes. If you cant, then you'll have to use `dynamic_cast` to deal with polimorphism.